# How to use carousel_slider with assets in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have been trying to use the carousel_slider tool in flutter but it does not seem to load up my asset images. I works when I change it to network images though. Could someone please tell me why. the code is below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:carousel_pro/carousel_pro.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:mindfulness/components/anxiety2.dart';

final List<String> imgList = [
  'assets/images/anxiety1.png',
  'assets/images/anxiety2.png'
  ];

class anxiety extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.pink[200],
      ),
      body: Builder(
        builder: (context) {
          final double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
          return CarouselSlider(
            options: CarouselOptions(
              height: height,
              viewportFraction: 1.0,
              enlargeCenterPage: false,
              // autoPlay: false,
            ),
            items: imgList.map((item) => Container(
              child: Center(
                  child: Image.asset(item, fit: BoxFit.cover, height: height,)
              ),
            )).toList(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What I found was that there was no need for a builder, the only parameters necessary were a list and an options parameter, so you can use the list to supply the assets one by one

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:carousel_pro/carousel_pro.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:mindfulness/components/anxiety2.dart';

class anxiety extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CarouselSlider(
      options: CarouselOptions(
        autoPlay: true,
        aspectRatio: 2.0,
        enlargeCenterPage: true,
      ),
      items: [
        Image.asset('assets/images/anxiety1.png'),
        Image.asset('assets/images/anxiety2.png'),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about you change your code to this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';

class ImageCarouselExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const ImageCarouselExample({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ImageCarouselExampleState createState() => _ImageCarouselExampleState();
}

class _ImageCarouselExampleState extends State<ImageCarouselExample> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  late CarouselSlider carouselSlider;

  List imageList = [
  'assets/images/loginimage.jpeg',
  'assets/images/smartanalytics.png',
  'assets/images/smartbiometrics.png',
  'assets/images/smarthmis.png',
];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            CarouselSlider(
              options: CarouselOptions(
                height: 250.0,
                initialPage: 0,
                autoPlay: true,
                reverse: false,
                enlargeCenterPage: true,
                enableInfiniteScroll: true,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                autoPlayInterval: Duration(seconds: 2),
                autoPlayAnimationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
                onPageChanged: (index, reason) => _currentIndex = index,
                // pauseAutoPlayOnTouch: Duration(seconds: 10),
                // scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              ),
              items: imageList
                  .map(
                    (item) => Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Card(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 10.0,
                          bottom: 20.0,
                        ),
                        elevation: 6.0,
                        shadowColor: Colors.redAccent,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                        ),
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                            Radius.circular(10.0),
                          ),
                          child: Image.asset(
                            item,
                            fit: BoxFit.fill,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                  .toList(),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: imageList.map((urlOfItem) {
                int index = imageList.indexOf(urlOfItem);
                return Container(
                  width: 10.0,
                  height: 10.0,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 2.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    color: _currentIndex == index
                        ? Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.8)
                        : Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.3),
                  ),
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 100)),
                FloatingActionButton(
                  heroTag: "btn1",
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainMenu()));
                  },
                  child: Icon(Icons.apps),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.red.shade800,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added them to pubspec.yaml? Watch out for indentantion, like [here](https://medium.com/@suragch/how-to-include-images-in-your-flutter-app-863889fc0b29).

After that stop an app and run it again, assets won't load if you hot restart.

Answer (score 0):

I try one of the examples in one demo app, and it works like this:
Image(image: AssetImage(item), fit: BoxFit.cover, width: 1000.0),

Of course, first look at the pubspec.yaml, and be sure you have added the images